# Prove that $6$ regular graph is connected

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

My question is how to check whether $6$ regular graph with $16$ vertices is connected or not?
I found that number of edges is $48$ and then because $48 < {15 \choose 2}$ we can't say anything about its connectivity. Is there other way to chech this?

Comment: You considered a graph with $48$ edges on $16$ vertices and found it need not be connected.  However you did not use the $6$-regular condition (which rules out having an isolated vertex, among other (im)possibilities).

Comment: Hint: Does there exists a 6 regular graph with 8 vertices?

Comment: Yes, so it does not mean it must connected. Thanks!